# Can't play embedded youtube video inside an iframe of an ionic app on iOS device after showing an ad with admob

Tags: ios, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, admob

I'm developing an app with Ionic and i have successfully implemented iframes showing YouTube content. On the browser everything works fine, but compiling it to iOS there is an issue. After showing an ad with admob. The iframe is not responding anymore when clicking the play button of the embedded youtube video. Without creating banner views or other ads, everything works fine.

Has anyone an idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Update: When I use a button which renews the src of the iframe with jQuery I can press the play button of the embedded video and watch it. In the code you see the workaround with showing the thumbnail of the video first and loading the embedded url after pressing the button.

The AdService

```
function AdService(admobSvc) {

    var service = {};

    service.ShowInterstitial = Interstitial;
    service.ShowBanner = Banner;

    return service;

    function Interstitial() {
       admobSvc.requestInterstitialAd();
    }

    function Banner() {
      admobSvc.createBannerView();
   }
}
```

The iframe

```
<div id="button-bar23" class=" button-bar ">
    <button ng-click="vm.play($index, trailer.embedded)" class=" button button-assertive  icon ion-social-youtube ">#{{$index + 1}} {{video.titel}}</button>
</div>
<div id="video-container{{$index}}" class="video-container">
    <iframe ng-click="vm.play($index)" id="video{{$index}}" src="{{video.thumbnail}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315"
                     style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function videoCtrl(ApiService, SharingService, AdService) {

    var vm = this;

    ...

    vm.play = function(index, embedded){
        console.log(index);
        $("#video"+index)[0].src = embedded;
    }

    vm.change = function () {
        AdService.ShowInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Route

```
angular.module('app.routes', []).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('menu.videos', {
            url: '/videos',
            views: {
                'side-menu': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/videos.html',
                    controller: 'videoCtrl as vm'
                }
            }
        })
        ...
```

Comment: 'Aren't working' is not a valid problem description. And do you expect someone to find a solution without seeing your code ?

Comment: @polku I was in a hurry. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't believe it but the old legends were true, some people can actually edit their questions in a correct way :) Sorry i can't help you though.

Comment: Are you using any plugin? Have you tried with https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova?

Comment: @Miquel Yes, I'm using this plugin, following this [example] (https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps)  Everything works fine, except the problem which i mentioned before.

Comment: Can't see how `vm.change` is binded to the html... Also, just to make sure, are you initializing ads with `autoShowInterstitial: true`?

Comment: @Miquel I'm using the controllerAs-Syntax (videoCtrl as vm) The controller is loaded via the $stateProvider. This is all working fine and the interstitial ads are showing. The problem is that after requesting interstitial ads, my embedded youtube videos inside of iframes can't be clicked anymore.

Comment: @cato1011 I still can't see how `.change` is being called but I believe you :). If you debug the app via usb (real device and chrome://inspect), what does it appear in the console when you click on the iframe? Is there any error? Maybe you can also get more info, i.e. if there is some layer above the iframe or javascript has been broken by some reason.

Comment: have you ever solved this? I am running into a similar issue, where I can still control the iframe but do not see the video anymore, only the audio.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this preference in your root project config.xml

`<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />`